# C float pointer to python numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, ctypes

I got a C pointer address where a float array is stored and the first value at offset 0 of that array is hardcoded to 13.0.

I load the pointer into python using:

```
data_pointer = C.cast(ptr,C.POINTER(C.c_float))
print 'value at offset 0: ',data_pointer[0]
```

However, the first value comes as  `6.41992237149e-10`

Any idea what is going on?

*I've validated the 'ptr' has the same value (address value) as the C array one, by printing both 'ptr' in python and my C program.*

Comment: "printing both 'ptr' in python and my C program" - hold on. Are these two different programs? If so, pointers don't work like that. There's [virtual memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory) and memory protection stopping one process from reading another process's memory.

Comment: I forgot to say, It's not two different programs. it's LLDB python code running from within a C program debugging session.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, it's Python code running in the LLDB debugger, which is a separate process. ISTM that you should be using the LLDB API to interact with the debugee. See [Using Scripting and Python to Debug in LLDB](http://lldb.llvm.org/scripting.html).